# flashing nuttx RTOS to stm32F4developer from windows

Tags: windows, rtos, flashing

I installed Ubuntu terminal as now Windows 10 supports it. I built the Nuttx RTOS using the terminal but in Ubuntu I cannot access USB devices except for a pen drive.

How can I flash the bin file to stm32f4developer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use windows tools.  All of the files in the Ubuntu "sandbox" can be access by Windows tools running outside of that sandbox.  In the top-level NuttX README:

Accessing Ubuntu Files From Windows

---

In Ubuntu Userspace for Windows, the Ubuntu file system root directory is
  at:

```
%localappdata%\lxss\rootfs
```

Or

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs
```

However, I am unable to see my files under the rootfs\home directory.
  After some looking around, I find the home directory
  %localappdata%\lxss\home.

With that trick access to the /home directory, you should actually be
  able to use Windows tools outside of the Ubuntu sandbox with versions of
  NuttX built within the sandbox using that path.

Comment: Disclaimer:  I haven't actually tried what I suggest.  It just seems to be reasonable.  But when using GDB there might be some issues with paths in the ELF binaries.  GDB might have issues locating source files.  I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 1):

As user6711188 explained you can access your home at %localappdata%\lxss\home or you can copy the nuttx.bin directly to Windows side:

$ cp nuttx.bin /mnt/c/ProgramData/

You will need to configure Windows Explorer to show Hidden files, this way you could see the nuttx.bin at C:\ProgramData

More info: https://acassis.wordpress.com/2018/01/10/how-to-build-nuttx-on-windows-10/